# How do I download GitHub Artifacts from Azure DevOps Release Pipeline

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow that creates Artifact(s).  I also have a last step within that workflow that triggers an Azure DevOps Release Pipeline.  I modified an existing release pipeline to change the artifacts from an ADO Build Pipeline to GitHub (and made the service connection in ADO).

```
- uses: Azure/pipelines@v1
  with:
    azure-devops-project-url: 'https://dev.azure.com/some_org/some_project'
    azure-pipeline-name: 'Name_Of_Release_Pipeline'
    azure-devops-token: '${{ secrets.ADOPAT }}'
```

So the issue is that the Release Pipeline will not retrieve nor download the associated build artifact from GitHub.  I can see that the GitHub workflow build information is stored in various Environment Variables, so the Release Pipeline is retrieving various metadata from the GitHub build, but why won't it download?

FYI - There is a ADO task that does download GitHub "release" artifacts but the GitHub repo I am building has not yet created a "release" and thus there are no artifacts to download.  So that doesn't help.

Comment: Are you talking about **classic** release pipelines, or YAML pipelines? The "GitHub" resource type is for cloning **repositories**, not downloading packages from GitHub Actions. Why not settle on one CI/CD toolset instead of trying to hack two of them to work together?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install the Azure DevOps extension "[**GitHub Actions**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sevaalekseyev.githubactions)" to your Azure DevOps organization where the release pipeline is in.

This extension contains two build/release tasks:

- **Run a GitHub Workflow**
- **Download GitHub Workflow Artifacts**

For your case, you can try to use the **Download GitHub Workflow Artifacts** task in your release pipeline to download the artifacts from the latest run of the specified GitHub workflow.